# Multiplicative inverse trouble in RSA Wikipedia entry

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I'm having a bit of trouble working through an example in the [RSA entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=RSA_%28algorithm%29&oldid=460514324#A_working_example).

At step 5, $d$ is calculated as $2753$. However, $d$, which is the multiplicative inverse of $e$, can be calculated by applying Bézout to $$ de - k\phi(n)=1 ,$$ correct? When I run that calculation using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bezout%2817%2C+eulerphi%283233%29%29), I get $-367$. I'm assuming that I'm doing something wrong and that the Wikipedia entry is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You (and Wolfram Alpha) got the right answer, so it is very likely that you set up things correctly.  Wikipedia also got the right answer. For note that $-367\equiv 2753\pmod{3120}$.  (In the Wikipedia article, $\phi(n)=3120$, and we are calculating the inverse of $17$ modulo $\phi(n)$.)

Any two numbers that have the same remainder on division by $3120$ are treated as being "the same" modulo $3120$. So for example $5873$ would also be a correct answer. Wikipedia chose to give the smallest positive integer that works. Wolfram Alpha chose to give the number of smallest *absolute value* that works.  There are legitimate arguments in favour of each choice.

Comment: Ah, okay. That was a really helpful answer. Thank you very much!